# What were the stats on the original Oso la Fez?

Tags: dnd-4e, familiars

I keep reading that it was amazing, fun, and completely unbalanced. But nowhere can I find the actual rules for it.

The current one in the character builder on the Wizards site is pretty unimpressive. It's at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drcw/2009june).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Dragon #375](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drcw/2009may)

Oso the Circus Bear

Speed 4, fly 6 (hover)

Constant Benefits: you gain a +2 bonus on Intimidate checks.

Active Benefits: Oso can speak any language you know, and can converse with other creatures. Unlike mere familiars, you can’t hear everything Oso hears and says unless Oso
lets you, and you would never be able to tell Oso what to
say.

As a minor action when Oso is in active mode, you can place a curse on one target in a square adjacent to
Oso. Until the end of the encounter, your attacks deal an
extra 1d6 damage to that target, exactly as the warlock’s
curse ability on page 131 of the Players’ Handbook. at 11th
level, you deal an extra 2d6 damage to a cursed target, and
at 21st level, you deal an extra 3d6 damage.

Oso deals 1d10 damage to anyone
who attacks him and misses. at 11th level, he deals 2d10
damage, and at 21st level, he deals 3d10 damage.

Comment: So, rules-wise, on the broken side of overpowered :)

Comment: But also awesome!

Comment: Nope, not even gonna try to finegle that one past my DM.

Comment: I believe there was also an "at some point in the campaign he will betray you horribly.  There is no way to escape this fate" tacked on to the original Oso, for balance purposes.